# Perform function if event is not called within time period

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I have a data fetching program in nodejs, and I want it to perform a function if an event has not happened within a certain amount of time.

```js
console.log("Fetching data.....");

// "verify" event called when data has been successfully found
fetcher.on("verify", function() {
    console.log("Data found!");
    process.exit(1);
});
```

So what I want to do is if the `verify` event is not called within 10 seconds, do `console.log("Fetching the data is taking longer than expected");`

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a timeout, and clear it when `verify` is called (or don't, since you are exiting the process anyways):

```
console.log("Fetching data.....");

const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Fetching the data is taking longer than expected");
}, 10000);

// "verify" event called when data has been successfully found
fetcher.on("verify", function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    console.log("Data found!");
    process.exit(1);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! It's been a couple of years since I last used Javascript. I just added the process exit because the original code was irrelevant